# print columns with AWK

Tags: awk

I tried to print only odd columns but I could not!

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $2*i-1}' file > test
```

but it prints everything in one column!

Would you please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `i+=2`:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }' file > test
```

For the new requirements, just make null the 'even' columns:

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) $i="" }1' file > test
```

Comment: I just find it, but another problem. everything will be in one column

Comment: would you please explain me why you have put 1 after }?

Comment: @MaryamSani: The `1` on the end forces `awk` to return true for each line, thereby enabling the printing of each line. It's the same as: `awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { $i="" } print $0 }' file > test` only more awkish. HTH.

Comment: A minor problem is that this `print $0` adds `OFS` after each column, even the one containing null.

Comment: @MarekŽidek Another solution, if you need the columns gone completely, is to build up a record of odd columns and print it out once the loop is exhausted: `awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) { r = (r ? r OFS : "") $i }; print r; r="" }' file`