# Printing only nth columns from csv file

Tags: perl, csv, awk, multiple-columns

I have a huge (about 1.7M columns, 2 lines each) .csv file, kinda like that:

```
Position 1 2 3 4 ... 1.6M
Coverage 1 1 1 2 ... 1
```

I need to extract the 1st and then the 1000th, 2000th and so on column until the end of the file. I'm a total newbie to programming and the like.  Is this feasible with perl or awk, and how? I have access to both Windows and Linux systems.
Thanks in advance!

Michael

Comment: so it is always 1st and then 1000K th?

Comment: awk has limited field length, only 100 fields. Try use gawk

Comment: @fedorqui yes, it is.

Comment: @morsik I already have gawk installed, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try this
gawk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=1000) print $i }' file > test 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716965/print-columns-with-awk)

Comment: @morsik your cmd will print all cols in one single column. also it print 1st, 1001st, 2001st ... cols.

Comment: What is the delimiter of your CSV?

Comment: @morsik 's code works almost perfectly! I can simply copy and paste the second column where I need it to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

give this line a try:

```
awk -v n=1000 '{printf "%s%s", $1, FS;
                for(i=n;i<=NF;i+=n)printf "%s%s", $i, (i+n>NF?RS:FS)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be simplified into a one-liner in Perl:

```
perl -lane ' for (@F) { print if !($a++ % 1000) } ' yourfile.csv
```

This uses the modulus operator `%` to check if a column number is a multiple of 1000 (or 0), and if so, prints the value. The `-a` switch splits the line on whitespace. If you want to specify a delimiter, e.g. `\t` you can do that with `-F"\t"`.

If loading a whole line into memory is slowing your program down, you can play around with the input record separator. In this example, I set it to space:

```
perl -l -0040 -ane '!(($.-1) % 1000) and print ' yourfile.csv
```

This will treat space as the input record separator, and read one column at the time. The `-l` option will `chomp` the "lines" and remove the space, and also provide newline for the print. `$.` is the current line number.

Answer (score 1):

Below `awk` program should do. Here I executed on a file which had 10000 records, the same can be done on any number of records.

```
$ awk '{for(i=0;i<=NF; i+=1000){printf("%s ", $(i==0?1:i))} print "" }' file
```

Output:

```
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 
1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but doesn't this just print a bunch of numbers for each line? The same numbers, no matter what's inside the input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this almost-readable perl:

```
$ cat foo.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $every = 1000;
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @columns = split(' ', $line);
    print "$columns[0]";
    my $i = $every;
    while ($i < @columns) {
        print " $columns[$i]";
        $i += $every;
    }
    print "\n";
}

$ perl foo.pl < input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try :

```
cat > ex.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2  1  1  3
```

and when oneline :

```
perl -e 'open FH, "ex.txt"; $line1=<FH>; $line2=<FH>; @tab1=split(/\s+/, $line1); @tab2=split(/\s+/, $line2); for ($i=0; $i<14; $i+=4) { print $tab1[$i]."/".$tab2[$i]."\n"; } close FH;'
```

result :

```
1/1
5/1
9/1
13/3
```

not in oneline:

```
# open file
open FH, "ex.txt";
# extract the two lines
$line1=<FH>;
$line2=<FH>;
# extract the elements for each 
@tab1=split(/\s+/, $line1);
@tab2=split(/\s+/, $line2);
# and print, here step 4
for ($i=0; $i<14; $i+=4) { 
  print $tab1[$i]."/".$tab2[$i]."\n";
}
close FH;
```

consumes lots of memory if you have 1.6 million of items!

Comment: Why not skip using your own handle and just use `<>`? This is a one-liner, so you're allowed to write abbreviated code.